# Syntax for specifying regular expression for the index.replace.regexp plugin of Nutch?

Tags: regex, nutch

I am following the documentation for the Nutch IndexReplace plugin posted at https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/IndexReplace and trying to setup regular expression that will create additional field storing information about the content type that will derived from the url.

Below is the property that has been added to my conf/nutch-site.xml file:

```
<property>
  <name>index.replace.regexp</name>
  <value>
    url:content_type=/.*wiki.example.com.*/wiki/
    url:content_type=/.*www.example.com.*/website/
  </value>
</property>
```

The goal is to create and populate the additional field content_type by either wiki or website, depending on which url the page has been fetched from. Both fields url and content_type get populated in my solr instance, but they both contain the full url, such as

```
sample fetched url: https://wiki.example.com/home
value of Solr field url: https://wiki.example.com/home
value of Solr field content_type: https://wiki.example.com/home
```

So it appears that the regular expression does not evaluate as expected in Nutch, although it evaluates as expected in the online regex tester at http://www.ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/java-visual-regex-tester/ .

Could you please clarify what is the correct regex syntax, such that for sample input url stated above, the fields are evaluated as follows?

```
url: http://wiki.example.com/home
content_type: wiki
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex worked correctly, but the problem was that the second regex overwrote the effect of the first regex. The following gave the desired effect (note that the regex is applied only when the urlmatch is evaluated as true):

```
<property>
  <name>index.replace.regexp</name>
  <value>
    urlmatch=.*wiki.example.com.*
    url:content_type=/.*wiki.example.com.*/wiki/
    urlmatch=.*www.example.com.*
    url:content_type=/.*www.example.com.*/website/
  </value>
</property>
```